# How to sort within a sql view

Tags: sql, view, sql-order-by

I've created a sql view and I need to sort the results of select by using the ORDER BY on 4 fields, but I'm getting message that ORDER BY cannot be used in views unless I use TOP.
Can someone explain why TOP is needed, and does someone have a workaround for sorting in a sql view?

Thanks.

Answer (score 18):

you don't need to sort a view. a view is like a table so you sort it when you select from it:

```
select * from yourView order by yourColumns
```

Answer (score 6):

**There is no guarantee the output of the view will be ordered**

Only the outermost ORDER BY applies for result sets: not any inner ones. So only this ORDER BY can be guaranteed to work:

```
SELECT col1, col2, FROm MyView ORDER BY col2
```

You can add it to views or derived tables and it forces "[intermediate materialisation](http://dataeducation.com/cursors-run-just-fine/)" because the results have to be ordered. However, for SQL Server 2005 and above, you have to use `TOP 2000000000` not `TOP 100 PERCENT` (except for that HF that Daniel Vassallo mentioned!)

Someone *will* use your view with a different order to that internally at some point too.

Answer (score 4):

You can try:

```
CREATE VIEW View_Products
AS
SELECT ProductID, ProductName, UnitPrice, CreateDate FROM Products
Order by CreateDate DESC
OFFSET 0 ROWS
```

Answer (score 0):

Would creating an index on the column with which you intend to sort the view help?