# MySQL - Add 'group by' rule on VIEW select

Tags: mysql, view, group-by

I have a VIEW with a id and status field.

```
select id, status
from inscricao_view;
```

It returns something like:

```
   id       | status
---------------------
   115      | authorized
   115      | paid
   231      | authorized
   231      | paid
   231      | authorized
   308      | paid
   308      | waiting_payment
   408      | waiting_payment
```

I'm trying to create another view that will return this one, but group by id.

This part is ok, the problem is that I need to prioritize the 'paid' status, so a select like:

```
select id, status
from inscricao_view_2;
```

Would return:

```
   id       | status
---------------------
   115      | paid
   231      | paid
   308      | paid
   408      | waiting_payment
```

I have tried use ORDER BY, which I know now that does not work on VIEWS. Any suggestions?

Comment: check https://stackoverflow.com/a/2010283/2469308

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya Thanks for the reply. The order by on the select sure works, but the ideia in this view is to already have this condition on, and than would be easy to set other filter paramerts, mostly to use datatables. If I find out how to do this view, the user would be able to choose filters easily.

Comment: Please share create view statement for  already existing `inscricao_view`

Answer (score 0):

Using [`Field()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_field) function, you can try the following:

```
SELECT id, status
FROM inscricao_view_2 
ORDER BY FIELD(status, 'paid') DESC, status
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The order by on the select sure works, but the ideia in this view is to already have this condition on the view, and than would be easy to set other filter paramerts, mostly to use datatables. If I find out how to do this view, the user would be able to choose filters easily

Comment: @Moisés are you looking for a create view statement ?